# Continuously redirect debugging information (e.g. *Messages*) to file

Tags: debugging, logging

My Emacs configuration (Emacs 27, Doom-Emacs config with lots of user-specific tweaks, running on MacOS) sometimes hangs at seemingly random times, and the `kill -SIGUSR2 <emacs PID>` has no effect. Debugging this would be a lot easier if there was a way to continuously redirect `*Messages*` and other debugging information to a log file, so I could identify what Emacs was doing (or trying to do) when it crashed.

Is there a way to continuously redirect/copy everything posted to the `*Messages*` and similar buffers to a file? Alternatively, is there a way to launch Emacs in "verbose" mode from the command line? Most of what I've found suggests running Emacs through `gdb`, but that's tricky (though not impossible) to set up on MacOS.

Comment: For a few years now, I routinely run Emacs through `gdb` on OSX 10.6.8 and through `lldb` on El Capitan so that I can catch any crash when it happens.  Who do you believe it is "tricky" to accomplish on your version of MacOS?  For `lldb`, my notes indicate that I had to give permission with `DevToolsSecurity -enable` and that gave me a confirmation of "*Developer mode is now enabled.*"..., but again that was on El Capitan.  For OSX 10.6.8, I run `ggdb` from MacPorts instead of the built-in `gdb`.  I have some notes regarding code-signing for `ggdb` on El Capitan, ....

Comment: My suggestion would be to bite the bullet by spending the time to get `gdb` working on your version of `MacOS`, build Emacs from source, and launch the binary from the `src` directory so that the `.gdbinit` is read ...  Then, the Emacs developers can help you debug and perhaps even fix the problem.  I spent quite a bit of time getting a newer version of `gdb` installed on my outdated version of Windows just so that I could obtain help from those Emacs developers who needed a specific debugging readout only available in newer versions of `gdb` ....